# using window.env variables to show/hide React component

Tags: html, reactjs

Is it good idea to show/hide React component using window.env

for example we have feature which we are not ready to release yet,so we are thinking of hiding it using window.env.FEATURE_ENABLED=0 (these vars will be picked by api call to service that serves bundle to browser)

But,I am thinking its risky since user can look at windows.env and set window.env.FEATURE_ENABLED=1 and start seeing the workflow which we intend to hide.

Could anyone please provide their take on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it could potentially be risky for the reason you say.

A better approach would be to only include finished features in the production build - unfinished features that are still in testing should not be sent to the client. For such features, have a separate build. Host it:

- On a local dev server (usually one running on the developer's personal machine) (great when one is making rapid changes), or
- On a [staging server](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/4205/staging-server#:%7E:text=A%20staging%20server%20is%20a,any%20new%20software%20or%20websites.) - one that's accessible to all developers, and works similarly to the live site, but isn't the same as the production URL

A staging server is the professional approach when multiple devs need access to it at once. It can take some work at first to integrate it into your build process, but it's worth it for larger projects.